# fileupload in aspcore api multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

so my fileupload is as following:

```
ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FilController : Controller
    {
        private IWebHostEnvironment iwebHostEnvironment;

        public void DemoController(IWebHostEnvironment _iwebHostEnvironment)
        {
            iwebHostEnvironment = _iwebHostEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(List<IFormFile> files) // få in i AddRequest metoden?
        {
            try
            {
                var result = new List<Filer>();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(this.iwebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", file.FileName); // ändra path stämmer inte fixa t databas senare
                    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    result.Add(new Filer() { Name = file.FileName, Length = file.Length });
                }
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```

the model is as following:

```
 public class Filer
    {
        public int filesID { get; set; }

        public long Length { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string meddelande { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i want the string 'meddelande' to be able to accept a string like this in postman:

[image: postman screenshot]

***whats the next step to add the 'meddelande' in the Upload method?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model binding in .net core will retrieve form fields by default,Yo can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources). You only need to add `string meddelande`  to your action parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(List<IFormFile> files,string meddelande)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(List<IFormFile> files, [FromForm] string meddelande)
{
   ...
}
```

Also a side note: I do not know Danish or Swedish or whatever language that is, and I do not know what meddelande means. But usually, if you expose a REST API, it would make sense to at least name the parameters English - just as you did with the files parameter.